# How to use Drive v3 in google app script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I have the following code that I would like to use Drive v3 in App Script

```
function myFunction() {
  let id = "<YOUR ODS FILE ID>";
  let file = DriveApp.getFileById(id);

  let fileBlob = file.getBlob();


  newFile = {
    name: "New File",
    mimeType: "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"
  }

  try{
    Drive.Files.create(newFile, fileBlob);
  }catch(e){
    Logger.log("Error");
    Logger.log(e);
  }
}
```

However by default the google app script only makes v2 available. The documentation does not seem so easy to do this migration directly in App Script.

How can I use Drive v3 in this code directly in the google app script?

Comment: The GAS [built-in](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive) and [advanced service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive) for Google Drive both leverage V2 of the API. To use V3 you'll need to make requests to the REST API directly using [`Url Fetch`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch).

Comment: @TheAddonDepot Can you help me how to use Drive v3 with url fetch?

Answer (score 2):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to convert the file of `let file = DriveApp.getFileById(id)` (ODS file from `let id = "<YOUR ODS FILE ID>"`) as Google Spreadsheet.
- You want to achieve this using Drive API v3 with UrlFetchApp of Google Apps Script.

#### Modification points:

- Although, unfortunately, I'm not sure about the file size of `let file = DriveApp.getFileById(id)` from your question, I think that in your situation, the file content is required to be sent as `multipart/form-data`. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#multipart)
- At Advanced Google services, this `multipart/form-data` is achieved at the internal server side. But, when you want to achieve this using UrlFetchApp, it is required to create the request body.

When above points are reflected to the sample script, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample script:

In this case, Drive API is used. So [please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

```
function myFunction() {
  const fileId = "<YOUR ODS FILE ID>"; // Please set the file ID.

  const metadata = {
    name: "New File",
    mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS,
    // parents: ["### folder ID ###"], // If you want to put the converted Spreadsheet to the specific folder, please use this.
  };
  const payload = {
    metadata: Utilities.newBlob(JSON.stringify(metadata), "application/json"),
    file: DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).getBlob(),
  };
  const options = {
    method: "post",
    payload: payload,
    headers: { authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() },
  };
  const url = "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart"
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options).getContentText();
  console.log(res);

  // DriveApp.createFile(blob)  // This is used for automatically detecting the scope of "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive".
}
```

#### Note:

- At `uploadType=multipart` method, the official document says as follows.

  > Use this upload type to quickly transfer a small file (5 MB or less) and metadata that describes the file, in a single request.

  - When you want to use the file more than 5 MB for this, please use the resumable upload. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#resumable)
- By the way, in your script, it seems that the ODF file on your Google Drive is used. In this case, you can also achieve your goal using the method of "Files: copy" in Drive API v3. The sample script is as follows.

  ```
    function myFunction2() {
      const fileId = "<YOUR ODS FILE ID>"; // Please set the file ID.

      const url = `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/${fileId}/copy`;
      const params = {
        method: "post",
        headers: {authorization: `Bearer ${ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}`},
        contentType: "application/json",
        payload: JSON.stringify({name: "New name", mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS})
      };
      const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
      console.log(res.getContentText())
    }
  ```

#### References:

- [Files: create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create)
- [Upload file data](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads)
- [fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)
- [Files: copy](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/copy)

Comment: I believe you understand what I want to do. But when I use your example I get the following error message

` 
Exception: Request failed for https://www.googleapis.com returned code 500. Truncated server response: {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "internalError",
    "message": "Internal Error"
   }
  ],
  "code": 500,
`

Comment: @Diego Resende Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. I proposed 2 sample scripts in my answer. But, from your replying of `when I use your example I get the following error message`, I cannot understand which script did you use. I apologize for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about the detail of your current script? By the way, when I tested my 2 sample scripts, no error occurs. The ODS file can be converted to Google Spreadsheet. I deeply apologize for this situation.

Comment: I used both scripts and I always get the same answer. The ODS file has 56 columns, 16,876 rows with data. The file has a size of 2mb. I just want to convert the ODS file to google sheets

Comment: @Diego Resende Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. So, in order to confirm your situation, can you provide your sample file for replicating your issue? By this, I would like to confirm it.